# Angularjs put advertising code inside partial views

Tags: angularjs

I need to place some advertising code (e.g 300x250 adv box) inside my partials views using AngularJS. The adv code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
simply_publisher = XXXXX;
simply_domain = XXXXX;
simply_space = XXXXX;
simply_ad_width = 300;
simply_ad_height = 250;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="//static.simply.com/simply_loader.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
</script>
```

Now, this part of code is placed inside my

```
templates/home_view.html
templates/single_view.html
templates/cat_view.html
```

And this code (only this!) **must be executed and refreshing after every change of url.**

I tried different things:

1) I put the code inside an external html file and i used the ng-include function. By the way the document.write insde the script (that load async content) causes blank screen with ONLY the adv box - without the rest of the application).

2) I tried to use a simple directive inside the partial view - same problem- the app redirect to a blank page with the only adv box without the views of the app.

3) I tried to use this code:

```
app.directive('script', function() {
     return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            if (attr.type === 'text/javascript-lazy') {
                var code = elem.text();

                var f = new Function(code);
                f();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And using - inside the partial view - the code of the adv with

```
type="text/javascript-lazy"
```

But not working...

Any ideas or suggestion?